# Where is Python Coverage .coveragerc file?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I'm using [Python Coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/) to see how much code my unit tests are covering. I want to use a config file in order to configure some coverage settings but I can't find where it is. It isn't in the same folder where `.coverage` is.
Also, Windows won't let me create it, as there is nothing before the extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I googled for a workaround, [finding a solution here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCreateAFileWithADotPrefixInWindowsExplorer.aspx). Create the file naming it as `.coveragerc.` (note the dot at the end!). Apparently it should accept the name. Try it out!

You should put the file ["in the same directory coverage.py is being run in"](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html).

Comment: Thanks man, It seems to work, another option is to specify a different name for the config file (and create a file with that name in the folder) by using:
`coverage run --rcfile=anyName.coveragerc ....`

Comment: Sure, that's another possibility. However, it complicates the `run` command for you and anyone else working with your project!